# Replacing a specific space with a word in a text file

Tags: python

Basically, I have a line in a text file that says:(ps address is fake)

- 7857 S. Griffin Drive New Kensington 15068
- 7407 Peninsula-St Harvey 60426
- 506 Shadow Brook Lane Park Forest 60466

And I want to insert "PA" after "Kensington" and before "150608" in the first line and "PA" after "HARVEY" and before "60426"
There should also be a comma before "PA"

The output should look like:

- 7857 S. Griffin Drive New Kensington, PA 15068
- 7407 Peninsula St Harvey, PA 60426
- 506 Shadow Brook Lane Park Forest, PA 60466

Comment: Are "Kensington", "Harvey" the only words after which you will be inserting "PA", or do you have a list, or you will be matching the pattern of the address?

Comment: What says `ps address is fake` ? Do you need the `', PA'` inserted before each 5-digit ZIP code at each line-end?

Comment: Any [example] that shows what you tried in code already?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not show us what you have tried and investigated so far, I suppose you just don't know how and where to start. So I'll give you a few hints how such a problem could be solved.

There are several ways how you can solve this problem. I'll tell you only one solution that uses a grammar parser. There may be also people who recommend Regular Expressions. This is also a good solution. Over the time you will make your experience what approach works well for what sort of problems. There are even much easier solutions (3-liners) that perfectly work with your examples (but may perfom bad in case you want to change the format). But I will concentrate here only on the grammar parser approach, because this is how I most likely would do it.

First you should know a bit about grammars and grammar parser. The theory is quite academic, but in practice everything is not so complicated.

Then you can use the Python the library Pyparsing. Pyparsing follows a simplified approach for grammar parsers by not distinguishing between a lexer and the parser. You may find out in the future what this means. At the moment this only means for you: Pyparsing is relatively easy in use.

With Pyparsing you define a grammar that reads your text. The most typical use case for Pyparsing and for grammar parsers in general is to create a nice data structure which represents the information of your input text, so that you can work with the data programaticaly.

But you actually don't even need the data structure. Once you have your grammar ready, Pyparsing has a function `replace_with`. That does all the magic for you.

This should be enough input for you. Just to motivate you. I think all the job will be done in less than 10 lines of Python code. Learning all this is definitively worth the effort. You need these skills very often in your life as software developer.